Why modified PC algorithm (searching for Bayesian structure) "in practice only considers a small subset of separating sets"?
I'll state how the text I'm reading describes PC algorithm.

This algorithm [9] starts with a fully connected graph  and, on the
basis of pairwise independence tests, it iteratively removes all  the
extraneous edges. To avoid an exhaustive search of separating sets,
the  edges are ordered to consider the correct ones early in the
search. Once a  separating set is found, the search for that pair
ends. The PC algorithm  orders the separating sets by increasing
values of size l, starting from 0 (the  empty set), until l = n 2
(where n is the number of variables). The  algorithm stops when every
variable has less than l 1 neighbors since it  can be proven that all
valid sets must have already been chosen. During the  computation, the
bigger the value of l is, the larger the number of separating  sets
must be considered. However, as l gets big, the number of nodes with
degree l or higher must have dwindled considerably. Thus, in practice,
we  only need to consider a small subset of all the possible
separating sets.

From what I understand, in the naive implementation of PC algorithm, we simply do an exhaustive search of all separating sets without sorting them. But it's best that we stop searching when all nodes no longer depend on a specific number of variables. My argument is if $X$ is dependent on, say, $\leq l - 1$ variables, we consider $X|(X_1, X_2, ...X_t)$ where $t \geq l$ then since $X$ dependent on less than $l$ variables, $X|(X_1,X_2,..., X_t)$ should just be $X$ conditioning on less than less than $l$ variables. This is a case we've only considered (when we're testing $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$)so we stop there.
What makes me stuck is this assertion:

During the  computation, the
bigger the value of l is, the larger the number of separating  sets
must be considered. However, as l gets big, the number of nodes with
degree l or higher must have dwindled considerably. Thus, in practice,
we  only need to consider a small subset of all the possible
separating sets.

How do you prove this mathematically?
